# Run my app from init.rc in Android

Tags: android, shell

I want to run my app in init.rc , I wrote a script :

```
#!/system/bin/sh
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -n my.package.name/my.package.name.MainActivity
```

this command work in terminal but when run

```
sh /system/bin/myscript
```

i got this error :

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=yaghuti.manshoor.possystemsample/.Main2Activity
 }

Error type 3

Error: Activity class {yaghuti.manshoor.possystemsample/yaghuti.manshoor.possystemsample.Main2Activity
} does not exist.
```

Comment: Have you got soln for this. I'm also facing the same issue. It'll be great help if you post the ans.

Comment: faced the same issue, you can find soln at - https://gist.github.com/ashutosh-mishra/863d7f3b0a3099842530244b8bb8696d